# Autoreponse destination email and Form Assembly

Tags: case-auto-response

I have configured FormAssembly to connect to my salesforce app. FormAssembly can trigger the Salesforce Auto Response rules, which works only if the contact already exists in my org. More specifically, I have an email address field in FA form, when submitted, I do a lookup on a contact based on that email.

The autoresponse sent by Salesforce is based on Contact.Email. Therefore, if the contact doesn't exist, no auto-response is sent, which is wrong. I would need the email to be sent to the address provided in the form.

As I am looking for a solution, my question is as follow : Where does Salesforce define the destination address of the Auto Response rule ?

It seems to be a non-modifiable option, but web-to-case can use the email "from" address and use it to answer so this let me think that it has to be configurable somewhere. My thought were that FormAssembly backend could change that value but I've been told that it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Form Assembly typically would work through Web to Lead. Since we have no idea how you have your org configured, it's difficult to say exactly what auto-response is being triggered. Most likely, you have some kind of auto-response rule set-up in your Web to Lead that is causing the email to be sent.

That having been said, you could also have an old trigger of some kind, lead assignment rule plus an auto-created task upon assignment that generates an email, or something else, that's been there since before you implemented Form Assembly that's causing the email to be sent. Regardless, I'd start my diagnosis beginning with Web to Lead.